# OpenGL ES 2.0 works on Windows and Linux but not on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a Qt app that uses a QOpenGLWidget for its main window. It draws using OpenGL ES 2.0, using QOpenGLFunctions to resolve the OpenGL functions. Everything works perfectly (using the same Qt app) on Windows and Linux. I use Qt 5 and Qt Creator on all three platforms.

However, on the Mac, drawing the graphics does not work. When I first tried running the app it crashed because it could not compile the shader programs, complaining that the 'precision' keyword was syntactically incorrect. This probably indicates that the shader compiler expects a different version of the shader language.

I tried inserting '#version 100' at the start of the shader programs, but that didn't help: the error message this time was that version 100 was not supported.

I found I could get some graphics on the display by deleting the 'precision' statements from the shaders. However, the display was incorrect - some graphics were missing. I discovered that only pixels with no transparency (alpha = 1) were drawn.

I am confident of the correctness of my use of OpenGL ES 2.0, because, apart from working under Qt on Windows and Linux, the same code also works perfectly outside Qt on Android (in native code) and iOS.

According the the Qt documentation, QOpenGLFunctions 'provides cross-platform access to the OpenGL ES 2.0 API'. That seems not to be true.

Is there a solution to this problem? I have spent a few hours searching and found nothing.

Comment: Are you using `QSurfaceFormat::setProfile()`? (Apple does not use the profiles like win/linux). If you're not using `Qt 5.1` maybe not, although `QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions()` should help you regardless in this scenario. If you are using `Qt 5.1` then `QAbstractOpenGLFunctions` could end up being helpful. http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtgui/qabstractopenglfunctions.html#details

Comment: I tried that. It didn't help. Asking explicitly for an OpenGL ES 2.0 context resulted in a black screen and a 'failure to create context' error. At the moment, by getting rid of 'precision' in the shaders, I have got everything working except pixel transparency, as noted above.

Comment: My only other suggestion at this point is to maybe take a look at this question (the author posts a solution to his issue). https://stackoverflow.com/q/23779357/499581

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fix. It works, but I'm still interested in better fixes and explanations of what exactly is going on.

The reason for the problem seems to be twofold: the shader compiler doesn't support the OpenGL ES version of the GLSL shader language, and the OpenGL ES implementation doesn't support all the blending modes, in particular `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.

Here's what you do:

1. Remove all the `precision` qualifiers or statements from the shader programs. This can be done in the standard way by adding `#define` statements to define `lowp`, `mediump` and `highp` as nothing, at the start of the shader program, and doing that only on the affected platform (Qt on the Mac).
2. Use the blend function `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`.
3. Use premultiplied alpha for all transparent colours.
4. When adjusting colours in the fragment shader, multiply all components of the colour by the alpha value: `gl_FragColor *= vec4(alpha);` instead of `gl_FragColor.w *= alpha;`. You need to do that so that you don't get R, G or B components greater than the alpha value, which is illegal when using premultiplied alpha and was probably the cause of transparent colours not being drawn.